# C Programming - returns not working as they should

Tags: c, function, parameters

I'm trying get the variables: float managerTotal, hourlyTotal, commissionTotal, and pieceworkerTotal from their respective functions to print in the switch statement case: 'q' in the choiceInput function. Yesterday I had lots and lots of errors and now I have them passing through but when I enter an input for the variables it doesn't pass the value through, they only return as 0. Please can someone help explain what I'm doing wrong. Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>


void welcome() {
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Welcome to the Factory A Payroll\n");
}

void choosePayroll() {
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Press '1' to access the Manager's payroll\n");
    printf("Press '2' to access the Hourly worker's payroll\n");
    printf("Press '3' to access Commission worker's payroll\n");
    printf("Press '4' to access Pieceworkers's payroll\n");
    printf("Press 'Q' to access Manager's payroll\n");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    choiceInput();
}

float managerIntro() {
    float managerTotal;
    char charReturn = 0;
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("You have selected 'Manager's payroll'\n");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Please enter your fixed weekly salary: $");
    scanf_s("%f", &managerTotal);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("You have entered $%.2f as the weekly fixed salary\n", managerTotal);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Press 'R' to return back to the main menu\n\n");
    scanf_s(" %c", &charReturn); // space before %c to tell scanf to skip the leading whitespace
    switch (charReturn)
    {
    case 'r':
        choosePayroll();
    default:
        printf("You have entered an invalid key, press any key to try again\n");
        getchar();
        getchar();
        hourlyIntro();
    }
    return managerTotal;
}

float hourlyIntro() {
    char charReturn = 0;
    float hourlyWage = 0;
    float hoursWorked = 0;
    float overTimeHours = 0;
    float normalPay = 0;
    float overTimePay = 0;
    float hourlyTotal;

    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("You have selected 'Hourly worker's payroll'\n");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Please enter the hourly wage for the worker: $");
    scanf_s("%f", &hourlyWage);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("You have entered $%.2f as the hourly wage.", hourlyWage);
    printf("\n-----------------------------------------------");
    printf("\nPlease enter how many hours the worker has worked this week: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &hoursWorked);
    printf("\n-----------------------------------------------");
    if (hoursWorked > 40) {
        overTimeHours = hoursWorked - 40;
        hoursWorked = 40;
    }
    normalPay = hourlyWage * hoursWorked;
    overTimePay = (hourlyWage * 1.5) * overTimeHours;
    hourlyTotal = normalPay + overTimeHours;
    printf("\nNormal weekly pay : $%.2f\nOvertime weekly pay: $%.2f\n\nTotal weekly pay: $%.2f\n\n", normalPay, overTimePay, hourlyTotal);
    printf("Press 'R' to return back to the main menu\n");
    scanf_s(" %c", &charReturn); // space before %c to tell scanf to skip the leading whitespace
    switch (charReturn)
    {
    case 'r':
        choosePayroll();
    default:
        printf("You have entered an invalid key, press any key to try again\n");
        getchar();
        getchar();
        hourlyIntro();
    }
    return hourlyTotal;
}

float commissionIntro() {
    char charReturn = 0;
    float basicSalary = 250;
    float itemAPrice = 0;
    float itemBPrice = 0;
    float itemCPrice = 0;
    float itemAQuantity = 0;
    float itemBQuantity = 0;
    float itemCQuantity = 0;
    float itemACommission = 0;
    float itemBCommission = 0;
    float itemCCommission = 0;
    float totalCommission = 0;
    float commissionTotal = 0;

    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("You have selected 'Commission worker's payroll'\n");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Please enter the price of Item A: $");
    scanf_s("%f", &itemAPrice);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Please enter the quantity of Item A sold this week: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &itemAQuantity);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Please enter the price of Item B: $");
    scanf_s("%f", &itemBPrice);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Please enter the quantity of Item B sold this week: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &itemBQuantity);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Please enter the price of Item C: $");
    scanf_s("%f", &itemCPrice);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Please enter the quantity of Item C sold this week: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &itemCQuantity);
    printf("\n-----------------------------------------------\n");

    itemACommission = itemAQuantity * (itemAPrice * 0.057);
    itemBCommission = itemBQuantity * (itemBPrice * 0.064);
    itemCCommission = itemCQuantity * (itemCPrice * 0.072);
    totalCommission = itemACommission + itemBCommission + itemCCommission;
    commissionTotal = totalCommission + basicSalary;
    printf("Commission for item A: $%.2f\n", itemACommission);
    printf("Commission for item B: $%.2f\n", itemBCommission);
    printf("Commission for item C: $%.2f\n", itemCCommission);
    printf("Total commission: $%.2f\n", totalCommission);
    printf("Total pay: $%.2f\n", commissionTotal);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Press 'R' to return back to the main menu\n\n");;
    scanf_s(" %c", &charReturn); // space before %c to tell scanf to skip the leading whitespace
    switch (charReturn)
    {
    case 'r':
        choosePayroll();
    default:
        printf("You have entered an invalid key, press any key to try again\n");
        getchar();
        getchar();
        hourlyIntro();
    }
    return commissionTotal;
}

float pieceworkerIntro() {
    char charReturn;
    float quantityItem1;
    float quantityItem2;
    float quantityItem3;
    float priceItem1 = 22.50;
    float priceItem2 = 24.50;
    float priceItem3 = 26;
    float payItem1;
    float payItem2;
    float payItem3;
    float pieceworkerTotal;

    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("You have selected 'Pieceworker's payroll'\n");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Please enter the quantity of Item 1 produced this week: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &quantityItem1);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Please enter the quantity of Item 2 produced this week: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &quantityItem2);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Please enter the quantity of Item 3 produced this week: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &quantityItem3);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");

    payItem1 = quantityItem1 * priceItem1;
    payItem2 = quantityItem2 * priceItem2;
    payItem3 = quantityItem3 * priceItem3;
    pieceworkerTotal = payItem1 + payItem2 + payItem3;
    printf("\nItem 1 pay: $%.2f\nItem 2 pay: $%.2f\nItem 3 pay: $%.2f\n\nTotal pay: $%.2f", payItem1, payItem2, payItem3);
    printf("Press 'R' to return back to the main menu\n\n");
    scanf_s(" %c", &charReturn); // space before %c to tell scanf to skip the leading whitespace
    switch (charReturn)
    {
    case 'r':
        choosePayroll();
    default:
        printf("You have entered an invalid key, press any key to try again\n");
        getchar();
        getchar();
        hourlyIntro();
    }
}

void returnMenu() {

}

float choiceInput(float *managerTotal, float *hourlyTotal, float
    *commissionTotal, float *pieceworkerTotal) {
    char userChoice = 0;
    scanf_s(" %c", &userChoice);
    do {
        switch (userChoice) {
        case '1':
            managerIntro();
            break;
        case '2':
            hourlyIntro();
            break;
        case '3':
            commissionIntro();
            break;
        case '4':
            pieceworkerIntro();
            break;
        case 'q':
            printf("Manager total is: $%.2f", &managerTotal);
            printf("Hourly total is: $%.2f", &hourlyTotal);
            printf("Commission total is: $%.2f", &commissionTotal);
            printf("Pieceworker total is: $%.2f", &pieceworkerTotal);
            exit(0);
        default:
            printf("You have entered an invalid key, please try again\n");
            getchar();
            getchar();
            choosePayroll();
            break;
        }
    } while (userChoice != 'Q');
}

int main(void) {
    welcome();
    choosePayroll();

    return 0;
}
```

Note: I apologise it's longish code, but the reason I've kept it that way is because the last time I made it shorter it didn't end up working for my actual code, only the short code I posted as an example.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I'll give it another go :) give me 5. If in the mean time anyone wants to give it a shot I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @Napstur no one is going to answer the question until it has a MCVE in the question itself.

Comment: No problem, I'm sorry guys. Just new here.

Comment: 1) `choiceInput();` : Need arguments. 2) `float choiceInput(float *managerTotal, float *hourlyTotal, float
    *commissionTotal, float *pieceworkerTotal) {` : Need return value. or Change return type to `void`. 3) `scanf_s(" %c", &userChoice);` Need buffer size --> `scanf_s(" %c", &userChoice, 1);` ...

Answer (score 0):

I made change in your code. Check it, if this change is not as per your requirement let me know.

```
#include <stdio.h>


float choiceInput();
void welcome();
void choosePayroll();
float managerIntro();
float hourlyIntro();
float commissionIntro();
float pieceworkerIntro();
float choiceInput();

int main() 
{
    welcome();
    choosePayroll();

    return 0;
}

void welcome() 
{
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Welcome to the Factory A Payroll\n");
}

void choosePayroll() 
{
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Press '1' to access the Manager's payroll\n");
    printf("Press '2' to access the Hourly worker's payroll\n");
    printf("Press '3' to access Commission worker's payroll\n");
    printf("Press '4' to access Pieceworkers's payroll\n");
    printf("Press 'Q' to access Manager's payroll\n");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    choiceInput();
}

float managerIntro() 
{
    float managerTotal;
    char charReturn = 0;
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("You have selected 'Manager's payroll'\n");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Please enter your fixed weekly salary: $");
    scanf("%f", &managerTotal);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("You have entered $%.2f as the weekly fixed salary\n", managerTotal);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Press 'R' to return back to the main menu\n\n");
    scanf(" %c", &charReturn); // space before %c to tell scanf to skip the leading whitespace
    switch (charReturn)
    {
    case 'r':
        choosePayroll();
    default:
        printf("You have entered an invalid key, press any key to try again\n");
        getchar();
        getchar();
        hourlyIntro();
    }
    return managerTotal;
}

float hourlyIntro() 
{
    char charReturn = 0;
    float hourlyWage = 0;
    float hoursWorked = 0;
    float overTimeHours = 0;
    float normalPay = 0;
    float overTimePay = 0;
    float hourlyTotal;

    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("You have selected 'Hourly worker's payroll'\n");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Please enter the hourly wage for the worker: $");
    scanf("%f", &hourlyWage);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("You have entered $%.2f as the hourly wage.", hourlyWage);
    printf("\n-----------------------------------------------");
    printf("\nPlease enter how many hours the worker has worked this week: ");
    scanf("%f", &hoursWorked);
    printf("\n-----------------------------------------------");
    if (hoursWorked > 40) {
        overTimeHours = hoursWorked - 40;
        hoursWorked = 40;
    }
    normalPay = hourlyWage * hoursWorked;
    overTimePay = (hourlyWage * 1.5) * overTimeHours;
    hourlyTotal = normalPay + overTimeHours;
    printf("\nNormal weekly pay : $%.2f\nOvertime weekly pay: $%.2f\n\nTotal weekly pay: $%.2f\n\n", normalPay, overTimePay, hourlyTotal);
    printf("Press 'R' to return back to the main menu\n");
    scanf(" %c", &charReturn); // space before %c to tell scanf to skip the leading whitespace
    switch (charReturn)
    {
    case 'r':
        choosePayroll();
    default:
        printf("You have entered an invalid key, press any key to try again\n");
        getchar();
        getchar();
        hourlyIntro();
    }
    return hourlyTotal;
}

float commissionIntro() {
    char charReturn = 0;
    float basicSalary = 250;
    float itemAPrice = 0;
    float itemBPrice = 0;
    float itemCPrice = 0;
    float itemAQuantity = 0;
    float itemBQuantity = 0;
    float itemCQuantity = 0;
    float itemACommission = 0;
    float itemBCommission = 0;
    float itemCCommission = 0;
    float totalCommission = 0;
    float commissionTotal = 0;

    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("You have selected 'Commission worker's payroll'\n");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Please enter the price of Item A: $");
    scanf("%f", &itemAPrice);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Please enter the quantity of Item A sold this week: ");
    scanf("%f", &itemAQuantity);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Please enter the price of Item B: $");
    scanf("%f", &itemBPrice);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Please enter the quantity of Item B sold this week: ");
    scanf("%f", &itemBQuantity);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Please enter the price of Item C: $");
    scanf("%f", &itemCPrice);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Please enter the quantity of Item C sold this week: ");
    scanf("%f", &itemCQuantity);
    printf("\n-----------------------------------------------\n");

    itemACommission = itemAQuantity * (itemAPrice * 0.057);
    itemBCommission = itemBQuantity * (itemBPrice * 0.064);
    itemCCommission = itemCQuantity * (itemCPrice * 0.072);
    totalCommission = itemACommission + itemBCommission + itemCCommission;
    commissionTotal = totalCommission + basicSalary;
    printf("Commission for item A: $%.2f\n", itemACommission);
    printf("Commission for item B: $%.2f\n", itemBCommission);
    printf("Commission for item C: $%.2f\n", itemCCommission);
    printf("Total commission: $%.2f\n", totalCommission);
    printf("Total pay: $%.2f\n", commissionTotal);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Press 'R' to return back to the main menu\n\n");;
    scanf(" %c", &charReturn); // space before %c to tell scanf to skip the leading whitespace    
    switch (charReturn)    
    {    
    case 'r':
        choosePayroll();
    default:
        printf("You have entered an invalid key, press any key to try again\n");
        getchar();
        getchar();
        hourlyIntro();
    }
    return commissionTotal;
}    

float pieceworkerIntro() {
    char charReturn;
    float quantityItem1;
    float quantityItem2;
    float quantityItem3;
    float priceItem1 = 22.50;
    float priceItem2 = 24.50;
    float priceItem3 = 26;
    float payItem1;
    float payItem2;
    float payItem3;
    float pieceworkerTotal;

    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("You have selected 'Pieceworker's payroll'\n");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Please enter the quantity of Item 1 produced this week: ");
    scanf("%f", &quantityItem1);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Please enter the quantity of Item 2 produced this week: ");
    scanf("%f", &quantityItem2);    
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Please enter the quantity of Item 3 produced this week: ");
    scanf("%f", &quantityItem3);
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");

    payItem1 = quantityItem1 * priceItem1;
    payItem2 = quantityItem2 * priceItem2;
    payItem3 = quantityItem3 * priceItem3;
    pieceworkerTotal = payItem1 + payItem2 + payItem3;
    printf("\nItem 1 pay: $%.2f\nItem 2 pay: $%.2f\nItem 3 pay: $%.2f\n\nTotal pay: $%.2f", payItem1, payItem2, payItem3);
    printf("Press 'R' to return back to the main menu\n\n");
    scanf(" %c", &charReturn); // space before %c to tell scanf to skip the leading whitespace
    switch (charReturn)
    {
    case 'r':    
        choosePayroll();
    default:
        printf("You have entered an invalid key, press any key to try again\n");
        getchar();
        getchar();
        hourlyIntro();
    }
}

float choiceInput()
{
    char userChoice;
    float managerTotal;
    float hourlyTotal;
float commissionTotal;
float pieceworkerTotal;

    scanf(" %c", &userChoice);
    do {
        switch (userChoice) {
    case '1':    
        managerTotal = managerIntro();    
        break;    
    case '2':
       hourlyTotal = hourlyIntro();
        break;
    case '3':
        commissionTotal = commissionIntro();
        break;
    case '4':
        pieceworkerTotal = pieceworkerIntro();
        break;
    case 'q':
        printf("Manager total is: $%.2f", managerTotal);
        printf("Hourly total is: $%.2f", hourlyTotal);
        printf("Commission total is: $%.2f", commissionTotal);
        printf("Pieceworker total is: $%.2f", pieceworkerTotal);
        return 0;
    default:
        printf("You have entered an invalid key, please try again\n");
        getchar();
        getchar();
        choosePayroll();
        break;
        }
    } while (userChoice != 'Q');
}
```